# Orange information score maximum value, in the context of bayesian and tree classifiers

Tags: python, bayesian, classification, orange

I am working with the Orange package and have written the following code based on the tutorials available:

```
import orange,orngTest,orngStat,orngTree,Orange
bayes = orange.BayesLearner()
tree=orngTree.TreeLearner(mForPruning=2)
bayes.name="bayes"
tree.name="tree"
data = Orange.data.Table("iris.tab")
learners=[bayes,tree]
results=orngTest.crossValidation(learners,data,folds=10)
print "Learner    CA    IS    Brier    AUC"
for i in range(len(learners)):
    print "%-8s    %5.3f    %5.3f    %5.3f    %5.3f" %\
    (learners[i].name,\
    orngStat.CA(results)[i],\
    orngStat.IS(results)[i],\
    orngStat.BrierScore(results)[i],\
    orngStat.AUC(results)[i])
```

This results in the following print:

```
Running script:
Learner      CA        IS     Brier    AUC  
bayes       0.920    1.402    0.098    0.993  
tree        0.940    1.447    0.120    0.967
```

Based on the following description of [Information Score](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00153760)

> Let the correct class of an instance be C. Recall that P(C) is the
>   prior probability of class  C and P'(C) is the posterior probability
>   returned by the classifier. We consider two cases:  (a) P'(C) > P(C) 
>   Here the probability of class C has changed in the right direction,
>   therefore we will  call such an answer useful. It should be awarded a
>   positive score.  Co) P'(C) < P(C)  Here the probability of class C has
>   changed in the wrong direction, therefore we will  call such an answer
>   misleading. It should be assigned a negative score.

Following:

```
Suppose the classifier in 1950 answered:   
P'(Bush) = 0.45   
P'(Dukakis) = 0.55   
P'(all others) = 0
```

Is a value greater than 1.0 invalid for information score?  Or is it the case that I have used the incorrect classifier on this type of data set, there are three distinct categories of data in the `iris.tab` data set.

Comment: Rolled this back to have the new tag of `information-score`.  It is a **valid** computer science term.

Comment: a tag being a valid CompSci term actually is not the point here; the point is whether the tag is one that people would logically 'follow' to look for questions pertaining to them. 'Meta' tags such as that pretty much never do, and they can distort the results in general.

Comment: @AndrewBarber just because it is an esoteric tag, does not in fact mean it is a meta tag.  If you can explain to me in some detail why information-score is a meta tag and not a full fledged tag I will gladly accept that.  However, information score has a specific meaning in the field of data mining / classification.  Further, it could be the case that this question belongs elsewhere such as a math.se or another sister site.  But, it is inappropriate at best to call something "meta" without giving an explanation outside of the weak one you have provided.